# res.write is not returning the expected value

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream, node.js-connect, node.js-client

This is the code:

```
var http = require('http')

var options = { 
    hostname: 'localhost',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 8000,
    path: '/'
}

var s = 3;

http.request(options, (res)=>{  
}).end(s+'')


http.createServer((req, res)=>{ 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'})
    var a = "";
    req.on('data', (data)=>{        
        a+= data
    })  
    req.on('end', ()=>{
        res.write(a)
        res.end()       
    })  
}).listen(8000)
```

Why might the server be returning invalid information to the client when a return value of 3 is expected?

Comment: Have you determined what is being returned currently by res.write()?

Comment: Currently does not return anything with the res.write()

Comment: Ok.  I would recommend taking a look at: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback.  Maybe you already have.  Anyways, they have a sample implementation on that page.

Comment: Have a look at [express](http://expressjs.com/) if you're trying to implement a node HTTP server. It abstracts away a lot of the details of working with the node `http` api.

Comment: I need it to work without use express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was a problem of visibility of variable a.

```
var http = require('http')
var a = '';
var options = { 
    hostname: 'localhost',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 8000,
    path: '/'
}

var s = 3;

http.request(options, (res)=>{  
}).end(s+'')


http.createServer((req, res)=>{ 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'})
    req.on('data', (data)=>{        
        a+= data
    })  
    req.on('end', ()=>{
        res.write(a)
        res.end()       
    })  
}).listen(8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does return 3, but in your example your not collecting it on your request..

Here is a modified version of your code that does the whole Request / Response, like a simple echo.

```
var http = require('http')

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 8000,
    path: '/'
}

var s = 3;

http.request(options, (res)=>{
  var str = '';
  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });
  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log('res: ' + str);
  });
}).end(s+'')


http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'})
    var a = "";
    req.on('data', (data)=>{
        a+= data
    })
    req.on('end', ()=>{
        console.log('req: ' + a)
        res.write(a)
        res.end()
    })
}).listen(8000)
```

Response ->

```
req: 3
res: 3
```

Comment: The res.write() doesn't work anyway. With the console.log worked before too.

Comment: In fact, if I launch the browser at the address, http://127.0.0.1:8000/, after I launched the program showing the white screen, then empty, instead of seeing the number 3.